# How can I use int** to pass a 2D array in C

Tags: c

Trying to work on leetcode #497 in C on my vscode. When writing main(), I am not sure how to deal with `int**` that leetcode provides. Is it possible to pass a 2D array using `int**`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct {
    
    int rectsSize;
    int * rectsColSize;
    int** rects;    
} Solution;

int points[100];

Solution* solutionCreate(int** rects, int rectsSize, int* rectsColSize) {
    
    Solution* sol = malloc(sizeof(Solution));
    sol->rects = rects;
    sol->rectsSize = rectsSize;
    sol->rectsColSize = rectsColSize;
    //some codes
    }
    return sol;
}

int* solutionPick(Solution* obj, int* retSize) {
    //some codes
    return ret;
}

void solutionFree(Solution* obj) {
    free(obj);
}

int main(void)
{
    int rects[2][4] = {{1, 1, 5, 5}, {6, 6, 9, 9}};
    int rectsSize = 2;
    int rectsColSize = 4;
    int retSize;
    Solution* obj = solutionCreate(rects, rectsSize, &rectsColSize);
    int* param_1 = malloc(sizeof(int));
    param_1 = solutionPick(obj, &retSize);
    solutionFree(obj);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused about where your problem is. Are you asking if its valid to pass an `int[][]` to something expecting an `int**`?

Comment: @DavidSullivan I guess it's not valid, but I wonder how leetcode use it to pass the array, because I want to test my solution offline so I need to write the main() function myself.

Comment: `int **rects` isn't technically a 2D array, even though 2D array syntax can be used (e.g. `rects[0][0]` works). Instead it's an array of pointers. Each of those pointers points to an array of `int`. So if you want a 3 row by 5 column array, you first need to allocate memory for an array of three pointers. Then for each of those three pointers, you need to allocate an array of five `int`.

Comment: "Is it possible to pass a 2D array using int**?" --> No.  `int **` matches a pointer to a `int *`.  With `int** rects` , the `rects` in `main` needs to be a a different type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While in general there are many different ways to handle 2D array, the simple answer is no. There is a lot of info about 2d arrays in C: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2565048), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3532894), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8041334), etc. In principle, when dealing with 2d arrays, every dimension except first to the left needs to be specified exactly. In your case, every rectangle is defined by 4 integers, so instead `int** rects` consider `int*[4] rects`. This makes `rectsColSize` useless, because now each column has constant size of 4 ints.

Just for completness: what you are trying to do is second approach to arrays, where each column has independent size, and (usually) additional malloc call. While this approach is also valid and requires `int**` type, it is not needed for your task. Nice description of the difference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10954740).

### Edit

Here is how to loop through `2d` arrays:

```
#define col 4
void print_2d(int (*a)[col], int aSize){
    for(size_t i = 0; i < aSize; i++){
        for(size_t j = 0; j < col; j++){
            printf("%d ", a[i][j]);
        }
    printf("\n");
    }
}
```

and here for `int**`:

```
void print_pp(int** a, int aSize, int* aiSize){
    for(size_t i = 0; i < aSize; i++){
        for(size_t j = 0; j < aiSize[i]; j++){
            printf("%d ", a[i][j]);
        }
    printf("\n");
    }
}
```

It seems that you want to convert `int*[4]` to `int**`, or more precisely, `int*[4] arr2d` *with* it's size `int arr2dSize` to structure `Solution`. In that case, here is wrapper to `solutionCreate`.

```
Solution* solutionCreateWrap(int (*arr2d)[4], int arr2dSize) {
    int* rectsColSize = malloc(arr2dSize * sizeof(int));
    int** rects = malloc(arr2dSize * sizeof(int*));
    size_t arr2dMem = arr2dSize * 4 * sizeof(int);
    rects[0] = malloc(arr2dMem);
    memcpy(rects[0], arr2d, arr2dMem);
    rectsColSize[0] = 4;
    for(size_t i = 1; i < arr2dSize; i++){
        rects[i] = rects[0] + i*4;
        rectsColSize[i] = 4;
    }
    sol->rects = rects;
    sol->rectsSize = rectsSize;
    sol->rectsColSize = rectsColSize;
    //some codes
    }
    return solutionCreate(rects, arr2dSize, rectsColSize);
}
```

Now for `int rects[2][4] = {{1, 1, 5, 5}, {6, 6, 9, 9}};` call `solutionCreateWrap(rects, 2)` will return initialised structure `Solution`. It looks gruesome, and it's details are even worse, so if it just works, you may skip the explanation. Understanding low level C details isn't neccesarily to write in it, and this (or any other) explanation cannot possibly cover this matter, so don't be discouraged, if you won't get it all.

`arr2d` is contiguous block of memory of `arr2dSize*4` integers. When multiplied by `sizeof(int)` we get size in bytes - `arr2dMem` in my code. Declaration `int (*arr2d)[4]` means, that `arr2d` is of type `int*[4]`. Knowing this we can cast it to `int*` like so: `int* arr = (int*)arr2d` and expression `arr2d[i][j]` is translated as `arr[i*4+j]`.

The translation to `rects` is as follows; `int**` is array of pointers, so every `rect[i]` has to be pointer to i-th row of `arr2d`. Knowing this, everything else is pointer arithmetic. `rects[0] = malloc(arr2dMem);` and `memcpy(rects[0], arr2d, arr2dMem);` copies whole `arr2d` to `rect[0]`, then every next `rects[i] = rects[0] + i*4;` is shifted 4 integers forward. Because `rect` is of type `int**`, the expression `rects[i][j]` translates to `*(rects[i]+j)`, and replacing `rects[i]` by `rects[0] + i*4`, we get `*((rects[0] + 4*i)+j)`, that is `rects[0][4*i+j]`. Note striking similarity between last expression, and `arr[i*4+j]`. `rectsColSize` is somewhat superfluous in this case, but it is essential in general `int**` array, when every subarray could have different sizes. After wrap function is done, `rects` is exact copy of `arr2d`, but with type appropriate for your `Solution` structure, so we can call `solutionCreate()`.

Comment: My only problem is that the `int** rects` is provided by LeetCode by default when I chose C. Though I think it to be weird, on leetcode it is okay to treat `rects` as a normal 2d array, where you can use rects[0][0] etc.

Comment: It's not weird at all. I might write my answer too sloppy, but `int**` is that second type of array - array of pointers. Anyhow the last link has nice explanation. Both arrays use the same syntax which may be confusing, because the difference is in memory layout.

Comment: Could you please show me an example of initialising and using that second type of array? I am now aware of the difference but still a bit confused.